How can I recreate the rpmdb?
I'm on Fedora 40 Workstation. I noticed that dnf was complaining about a corrupt sqlite database and I tried to fix it by following an online tutorial. I thought I made a copy of the rpmdb files, but I was wrong [^1].
Now the system doesn't know about any installed RPM files. Is there a way to fix this without reinstalling?

[^1] I thought copied the directory /var/lib/rpm. What I didn't realize was that it's now a symlink and I copied that instead. The moral of the story is, that you have to drink your coffee before attempting system-breaking changes!

did you tried  rpmdb --rebuilddb ?

Yes, I tried rpm --rebuildbd. It created an empty database.

Would you show the full error message?

The original error was "SELECT hnum, blob FROM 'Packages': 11: database disk image is malformed". Now there is no error message, but the database is empty.

So, it's not 100% fixed, but the best thing I came up with is to install Fedora in a VM and copy the rpmdb files from there.
[UPDATE]
Here are some more details:

Obviously use the same version of the OS.
Make sure to copy the database before installing any updates in the guest OS. Otherwise RPM/DNF would "think" you have the latest packages installed and won't update them.
After replacing the broken files with the ones from the VM update your system.
(Re)install stuff that you had before, like the nvidia drivers.
There may be some old kernels left (ls /boot) for which the system no longer has records that they are installed. I think the cleanest way to deal with them is to install the exact same versions of the RPM packages and then uninstall them. I haven't done this yet. I'll update here when I do.

